# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The given attribute is only supported on the PDOStatement object

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, yii

I'm a beginer in Yii framework programming. Wanting to use Gii extensions, I am unable. Certain features, such as Crud generator, generate exceptions.

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The given attribute is only supported on the PDOStatement object.
```

[image]

In my `main.php` config file, I have the following portion of code related to the connection string, import and the modules variables :

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
            'ext.giix-components.*',
        //additionally added for Giix
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'pass',
                    'generatorPaths' => array('ext.giit-core'),
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','192.168.0.83'),

    ),

),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=192.168.0.2;Database=DBStage',
        'emulatePrepare' => FALSE,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
                    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl',
    ),
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: dear, you have two `db` connections with same name and different data. Please comment your sqlite connection.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected, but the exception remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've needed to precise the `CDbConnection` class and remove the `emulatePrepare` and `tablePrefix` entries in my `db` variable array. Not it looks like this and works as well. But, I've lost a day for this.

```
'db'=>array(
    'class' => 'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=192.168.0.2;Database=DBStage',
    //'emulatePrepare' => FALSE,
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
                //'tablePrefix' => 'tbl',
),
```

Hoping it will help somebody.

Comment: I waste just one hour till I found your solution, thank you!

Comment: Helped me with Yii2, using the yii\db\Connection class. Setting 'emulatedPrepare' to NULL [Default] or removing worked. Thanks!